# Mocking functions for acceptance testing in F#

Tags: dependency-injection, f#, functional-programming, mocking

I have a function which generates random numbers. When acceptance testing, I want to replace this with one that generates known numbers.

In an object oriented language I would use dependency injection and simply wire up this component differently in the test set-up. The only way I can see to do this in a functional language is to pass the dependency through the program, from the root, until it gets to the function that needs it (is "turtles all the way down" the correct phrase here?).

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous options - you could pass the function around, you could use a dependency injection mechanism (many of the standard .NET libraries will work in F# but you may find some F#-specific lightweight tools too) or you could even use monads to pass the state around implicitly.

However, do you need to make the choice between *production* and *testing* set-up at runtime? If no, you could just move the functions that you want to implement differently for testing into a separate file and have two different builds of your project.

This might not be as pure solution, but it is super simple (just use `Random.Test.fs` instead of `Random.Runtime.fs`) and it is nicely functional - you just provide different implementation of a single (or multiple) functions and the rest of the code uses them.

Comment: The lattermost would be my thought, too. F# does something sort of similar when you call 'open Checked'. It just outscopes (e.g.) the (+) operator with a new one. You could do something similar with regard to your Random number generator without changing the code under test.

Comment: @mwilson That's right - using a different `open` (perhaps in `#if`) would be another way to do that. I think this makes more sense in F#, because the program tends to be structured using functions in separate modules (in different files) and so you can just reference different module or file. The same would be more difficult in C#, where functionality is more interconnected.

Comment: I've marked as answer, but I still consider these options something of a hack. If I did want runtime flexibility in a pure functional language, is passing the function from the input the only way? Are there any good resources for composition patterns in functional languages?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do it in a *pure* functional language is to thread the state all the way through.  F# is impure, so you can do it the typical way you do it in OO.  But I am unclear if you're asking about pragmatics or about how functional designs tackle the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have something like the following:

```
let generateRandomNumber =
    let generator = new System.Random()
    fun () -> generator.Next()

let addFiveToRandomNumber() =
    let next = generateRandomNumber()
    next + 5
```

where `addFiveToRandomNumber` is the function you'd like to test.

A good solution to your problem, and generally good practice in F#, is to disentangle your pure and impure functions:

```
let generateRandomNumber =
    let generator = new System.Random()
    fun () -> generator.Next()

let addFiveToGeneratedNumber generator =
    let next = generator()
    next + 5

let addFiveToRandomNumber() = addFiveToGeneratedNumber generateRandomNumber
```

Now the function you want to test is `addFiveToGeneratedNumber`, e.g. `addFiveToGeneratedNumber (fun () -> 1)` should always return 6. I probably wouldn't even bother testing `generateRandomNumber` or `addFiveToRandomNumber`.

So here our solution is to "pass in the dependency", but it doesn't have to come all the way from the root.

Comment: That's fine in a unit test, but I'm talking about an acceptance test here.